# How To Add Launch Arguments & Environment values on iOS Extension In UI Automation Test

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, xcuitest

I've got a UIAutomation test that tests an app with a Share Extension.
I want to pass in some launchArguments and launchEnvironment properties to the Share Extension in my test.

I can't figure out a way of doing it.

When debug the ProcessInfo in the extension my values aren't there.
I've tried setting them like this:

```
XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:"com.my.app").launchArguments = ["TEST"]
XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier:"com.my.app").launchEnvironment = ["TEST":"TEST"]
```

and this:

```
XCUIApplication().launchArguments = ["TEST"]
XCUIApplication().launchEnvironment = ["TEST":"TEST"]
```

Note, I am correctly getting the correct process when I'm finding it with the bundle identifier.